# create a DIV that would take an input type with 4 digits with fields that will be used to collect the credit pins for authentication using html only

Tags: html

create a DIV with an attribute of data-cc-digits. It should contain four INPUT text fields, each with a size of 4 and a placeholder of ---- (4 dashes). These fields will be used to collect the credit numbers

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site.  This isn't a forum where we do your work for you, you need to have attempted something and if you get stuck with your code, ask a question about it

Comment: <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----"></input>
       <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----"></input>
     <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----"></input>
    <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----"></input>  
      </div> solved it with this already